# Difference between setRootPath and setRootIndex in QFileSystemModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qfilesystemmodel

I'm new to QFileSystemModel class but I'm confused with the functions of setRootPath and setRootIndex

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`QFileSystemModel` is a model and inherits from `QAbstractItemModel`, so each element of the structure has a `QModelIndex` associated with it

from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#basic-concepts:

[image]

The QModelIndex is a temporary representation of the items that stores the information of its location within the structure.

In the case of `QFileSystemModel` is a model of type tree so it has as root a `QModelIndex`, and this can represent any directory, so to establish what is the root there is the [`setRootPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setRootPath) method:

> **QModelIndex QFileSystemModel::setRootPath(const QString &newPath)**
>
> Sets the directory that is being watched by the model to newPath by
>   installing a file system watcher on it. Any changes to files and
>   directories within this directory will be reflected in the model.
>
> If the path is changed, the rootPathChanged() signal will be emitted.
>
> Note: This function does not change the structure of the model or
>   modify the data available to views. In other words, the "root" of the
>   model is not changed to include only files and directories within the
>   directory specified by newPath in the file system.

But also keep in mind that a model can be used by several views, and each view could show different sub-parts of the model (for example different sub-directories) so the `rootIndex()` of the model should not be the root that is shown in the view. To do this, the views that inherit from `QAbstractItemView` have the [`setRootIndex()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setRootIndex) method:

> **void QAbstractItemView::setRootIndex(const QModelIndex & index)**
>
> Sets the root item to the item at the given index.

In conclusion, the `QFileSystemModel` has a `rootPath` that indicates the root from where the files will be monitored, and the views have a `rootIndex` that tells them which part of the model to show.

Example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileSystemModel, QTreeView, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    lay = QHBoxLayout(w)
    model = QFileSystemModel()
    model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
    for dirname in (QDir.rootPath(), QDir.homePath(), QDir.currentPath()):
        view = QTreeView()
        view.setModel(model)
        view.setRootIndex(model.index(dirname))
        lay.addWidget(view)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]